# Collection View Grid iOS Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, grid, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

So I have a working collection view with 2 columns and 3 items in each column. The grid view works great until I get to the iPhone 5s simulator, and then my grid view turns into one single column instead of 2. I've read a bunch of posts about custom layouts but none of them seem to work. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height


    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (screenWidth - 32)/2, height: 175)

    var collview = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), collectionViewLayout: layout)


    [collview.reloadData];


}  
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    let myImage = UIImage(named: pictureArray[indexPath.row])

    cell.textView.text = textArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.imageView.image = myImage


    return cell
}

override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return pictureArray.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: 175, height: 175)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you set the size for each item is `CGSize(width: 175, height: 175)`, so when you change other phone, it will not work well.

Just change like this: (change `UICollectionViewDelegate` to `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: screenWidth / 3, height: screenWidth / 3)
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error that says "value type of UIView had no member size"

Comment: I have just updated the answer, please check again. You can use collectionView.size.frame.width / 3

Comment: weird, now it's saying that value of UICollectionView has no member size. Did I do something wrong in my code?

Comment: So, you can use screenWidth / 3

Comment: awesome, that works but now my cell sizes are smaller than what they should be. I want the height and width of the cell to be 175 and I think they are defaulting to 50.

Comment: No, you look again the height, I set it equal to the width, you can change it yourself :)

Comment: ohhh okay, that kind of works but now my cells are kinda spread and don't display the whole image. Am I using the code right?  `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height
        
    
        return CGSize(width: screenWidth / 3, height: 175)
        
    }` sorry for so many questions

Comment: Did you set the auto layout for your image in your cell??

Comment: yep, I made it 175 by 175 on the main.storyboard

Comment: No, don't set like this. use autolayout, because 175 pixels in IPhone4 and Iphone6 will display different

Comment: I think auto layout is already enabled. what do you exactly mean? I have the image view set up to be 175 x 175 and the cell view 175 x 175. Do I just put zero for those values? Forgive me, I'm fairly a beginner to swift

Comment: Don't set the width and height of the image, you must autolayout it to the superView

Comment: how do I do that? do I do that in my viewDidLoad?